# router.get query params dont work on express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to build and express app.
In this code :

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/:id", ControllerHandler(UserController.getSingle, GetUserRequest));
router.get("/", ControllerHandler(UserController.getAll));
```

what is wrong with the line3 thatdoesnt work?
line 4 is completely ok
When I delete the line 4 and try to make a request to localhost:3000/users/?id=1 it sais :
Cannot GET /users/

I tried to change the cotations , use Regex , and everything but it wont even go through my controller .
but everything with line4 is ok

Comment: line 3 should be caled like `localhost:3000/users/1` and access in code as `req.params.id`

Comment: Both of these URLs won't resolve `/users/?id=1`, do you mean `/users?id=1`? what's your base path? is it `/users`? What's `ControllerHandler` it is impossible to understand what you are doing there. Please provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this isn't your complete code as both requests shouldn't resolve to `localhost:3000/users` they should resolve to `localhost:3000` but the issue is with the request URL. To hit `/:id` your URL should be localhost:3000/users/1 as this `router.get("/:id", ControllerHandler(UserController.getSingle, GetUserRequest));` accepts params (req.params) and `router.get("/", ControllerHandler(UserController.getAll));` accepts `localhost:3000/users/?id=1`
which is query (req.query). Both are different methods of passing data in get API.

[Here](https://dev.to/gathoni/express-req-params-req-query-and-req-body-4lpc) is a good explanation of and difference between them.

Comment: Thanks a lot . it worked and I was being stupid